# Need to check the size of root directory from remote server

Tags: javascript

I am not able to find the size of root directory of remote ftp/sftp server

I have tried `ls -l` and `du -sh` commands, nothing worked

```
vars.filepath = "sftp://username:password@abc.server.com/root/";
cmd = "ls -l "+vars.filepath;
vars.res = execCommand(cmd, true);
logInfo("size : "+ vars.res);
```

It should give me the size of the root directory in MB excluding the sub directories size.
 
With `ls` and `du` commands it gave me

> -53,cannot access 
>   sftp://username:password@abc.server.com/root/ No such file or directory

But when I try to connect to `FTP/SFTP` through `winscp/filezilla` it works.

Comment: Are you using this [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Syntax) or is this some custom function or from some library?

Comment: This function is from a library

Comment: Has this library some name?

Answer (score 1):

You can only run commands on the local system using SFTP. Run help to see what commands are available:

sftp> help

I don't think `du` is available with sftp from command line, you would need to us ssh instead

You could just use SSH but if JS is a must ssh-exec should work

### Not tested but should be pretty close

#### Run

```
npm i ssh-exec
```

#### create file ssh.js

paste :

```
var exec = require('ssh-exec')

//option  1  requires id_rsa as private key
 exec('ls -lh', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com').pipe(process.stdout)

// option 2 
//USE  ENV VAR LIKE $MY_PWORD DONT HARDCODE PW
exec('du -sh /PATH/TO/DIIR', {
  user: '"userName",
  host: 'my-remote.com',
  key: myKeyFileOrBuffer,
  password: '$MY_PWORD' 
}).pipe(process.stdout)

/// option 3 what you are trying to do with sftp
exec('ls -lh', 'ubuntu@my-remote.com', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(err, stdout, stderr)
})
```

Comment: how to use ssh in javascript?